# Is there a reliable way to define the scale label's position in a groupplot in relation to the respective label?

Tags: pgfplots

I was asked to try and put the scale labels for the `ytick`s *not* right above the north west corner of the plot as it is rather unusual. Personally, I tend to agree. It works easily but `above left` might be a bit better. But actually, putting it right above the label for the y-axis, then rotated 90 degrees, is preferable.

Based on Jake's post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115490/pgfplots-scale-legend-position-when-below-xlabel/115539#115539), I got the idea to position the scale right above the `ylabel` by anchoring it to the `ylabel` node for each groupplot. But this does not work for a groupplot for reasons I have not yet figured out.

But all in all, I intended to use a reliable method to anchor the scale labels to `xlabel` and `ylabel` because fine-tuning the positions is an immensely time-consuming task. :(

Is this possible, to anchor the tick scale labels at the north end of the `ylabel` in a groupplot?

### Really cool mockup of what I would like to have (the blue, funny looking scale labels are the ones I want, please imagine the red one right next to the `xlabel` as well)

[image]

### MWE (does not work)

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
tikz,
pgfplots,
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

%\pgfplotsset{
%x label style={at={(rel axis cs:0.5,-0.15)}, name=xlabel},
%y label style={at={(rel axis cs:-0.2,0.5)}, name=ylabel},
%}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group size=2 by 1,
horizontal sep=0.2cm,
vertical sep=1.5cm,
ylabels at=edge left,
yticklabels at=edge left,
},
%
ymin=300,
ymax=1300,
%
xlabel={The label for the x-axis},
ylabel={Some y-values},
%
xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0.5,-0.15)}, name={xlabel} },
ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:-0.2,0.5)}, name={ylabel}},
legend style={at={(xlabel.south)}, anchor=north, yshift=-1ex},
%
every x tick scale label/.append style={
    at={(xlabel.east)}, anchor=west, inner sep=0pt
},
every y tick scale label/.append style={
    at={(ylabel.north)}, rotate=90, anchor=south, inner sep=0pt
},
%
scale ticks above exponent={2},
]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(2000,1200) (3000,500)};
\addlegendentry{Word}
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(2000,1200) (4000,400)};
\addlegendentry{Text}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A simple solution would be to define macros and use the macros in each plot.  \def\ymin{300) ...  ymin=\ymin

Comment: Come to think of it, you could set the value using \pgfkeys, but you would need to know its full name.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I think there was a misunderstanding. Or I am not smart enough to apply the bits in your comments to the problem.

Comment: @henry: I'm not sure I understand exactly where you want the scale label to go. Could you maybe add a mock-up of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were just trying to get several plots to have the same scale.

Comment: @Jake Edited the op. :)

Comment: @henry: Ugh, this would requires some serious changes to a lot of internal macros. I don't suppose you'd be happy with a manual solution? If you define a new key `\pgfplotsset{ henry's scale label/.style={ y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1/(1e#1)}, ylabel/.append={$\ \cdot{10^{#1}}$} } }` you can call `henry's scale label=3` in your `axis` options to get the desired output.

Comment: @Jake Hm, that is a good idea. But I'll rather use the vanilla code then, i.e. to put it above the y-values then, via `at={(0,1)}, above left, yshift=SOMEVALUE`. "Less code is better", kind of... sort of. :) Thank you for looking into it, I appreciate it.

Comment: You could pre-compute the scale factor (power of 10) yourself and apply it to the data.  I've already got code to do that somewhere.

Comment: @Jake In hindsight, your code might prove to be ideal after all. :) Will try it out asap.

Comment: @Jake It works like a charm... for the y-values, that is. Hm, but I can't really pinpoint why the values which are used are transformed ... what gets displayed, say when a value of 1500 is taken out of the respective data file? 1.5 or 1500? Btw I suppose it's simply in analog form for the x-values?

Comment: @Jake Hm, also the actual label content (=text) gets shifted due to the extra content. All in all, what will I choose, the devil or the deep blue sea. :P I think it's worth saying that once one has figured out the 1. font, 2. font size and 3. the shift, the vanilla method is equally, um, pleasant to work with. ;)

Comment: @Jake Can I add an `xshift` command exactly the length of whatever length `henry's scale label` might add to the original `xlabel`?

Comment: @henry: To avoid shifting the `xlabel`, you can simply attach the scale label to the side of the `xlabel`. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in a fully automatic fashion is quite hard and would require serious changes to several internal macros. If you can live with a semi-automatic solution where you provide the scaling exponent manually, you could define a new style

```
\pgfplotsset{
    henry's scale label/.style={
        y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1/(1e#1)},
        ylabel style={
            append after command={
                node [rotate=90, anchor=base west] at (\tikzlastnode.base east) {$\cdot{10^{#1}}$}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which in your example you would call using `henry's scale label=3`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    henry's scale label/.style={
        y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1/(1e#1)},
        ylabel style={
            append after command={
                node [rotate=90, anchor=base west] at (\tikzlastnode.base east) {$\cdot{10^{#1}}$}
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group size=2 by 1,
    ylabels at=edge left,
    yticklabels at=edge left,
},
ymin=300, ymax=1300,
xlabel={The label for the x-axis},
ylabel={Some y-values},
scale ticks above exponent={2},
henry's scale label=3
]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(2000,1200) (3000,500)};
\addlegendentry{Word}
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(2000,1200) (4000,400)};
\addlegendentry{Text}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This workaround breaks the solution found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192361/how-can-i-add-zero-lines-to-a-groupplot/192456#192456) to draw zero lines for every plot. The plots who get assigned the option to use this custom scale label, do not get the respective zero line drawn anymore.

Comment: But unfortunately, using `execute at begin plot={\draw[thin] (current axis.left of origin) -- (current axis.right of origin);\draw[thin] (current axis.above origin) -- (current axis.below origin);},` does not lead to satisfactory results (read: really ugly and factually wrong) => [click here for picture](http://imgur.com/zI9yklE). Could you please give some advice for this? :) Also, random note: one can not use the `restrict VARIABLE to domain` key with this, it does not produce useful results then.

Comment: Another note: this "breaks" (for the lack of a better word) the method to define coordinate based upon another, by using syntax like: `\draw
(0,1) coordinate (x1)
($(x1)+(1.5cm,0.33cm)$) coordinate (x2)
;`. It's back to `[yshift=...]` then. Neither does `shift={(1.2cm,0.25cm)}` work.

Comment: @henry: I'm not sure what you mean by "breaks" in this last case. The `calc` syntax shouldn't be influenced by this code. Could you maybe ask a new question about this_

Comment: I figured out the `restrict VARIABLE to domain` method in the meantime. One has to multiply/divide these border values with/by the scale factor on defines. So in that regards, I take that back. It's fine.

Comment: About that last case: damnit, I can't reproduce it. :( :( It works as expected in an MWE but not in my big document. :(